# AutoFac: Inject NULL values

Tags: c#, null, autofac

I want to use AutoFac to inject the current principal in the objects that need it. Suppose I have an object (`AuthorizationValidator`) that is performing security checks. It looks something like this:

```
public AuthorizationValidator : IAuthorizationValidator
{
  public AuthorizationValidator(IDataAccess dataAccess, IPrincipal principal)
  {
     // Save injected objects
     ...
  }

  public bool CheckPermission(Guid objectId, Action action)
  {
     // Check if we are authorized at all
     if (this.principal == null)
       return false;

     // Check the permission in the database
     ...
  }
}
```

For my web application the AuthorizationValidator is registered and I use the following registration to inject the principal:

```
builder.Register<IPrincipal>((c, p) => HttpContext.Current?.User);
```

Other type of applications use the thread's principal or something similar. All object that require the principal get the proper principal injected.

If a call is made without authorization, then AutoFac raises an exception telling me that it cannot provide the `IPrincipal` object, because the factory returned `null`. In this case, an empty principal is fine and shouldn't raise an exception.

Comment: I dno't know what is inside Autofac, but there is a chance that this could work : `builder.Register<IPrincipal>((c, p) => (IPrincipal)HttpContext.Current?.User);`

Comment: Generally speaking, IoC frameworks won't let you inject null intentionally. That's not just an Autofac thing.

Comment: Would the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) be an alternative as I've suggested in my answer?

Comment: Although I ended up to use a principal provider that returns null if it doesn't have a principal, I think in most situations the Null Object pattern might be better, so I marked it as the best answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Autofac [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#property-injection) they recommend to use the [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for such scenarios. You could create a `NullPrincipal` class that inherits from the `IPrincipal` interface with a private constructor that only exposes a `readonly` `static` field which provides the default instance. Then you can return this instance instead of null:

```
builder.Register<IPrincipal>((c, p) => HttpContext.Current?.User ?? NullPrincipal.Default);
```

Of course you would have to update all places in your code where you are checking if the principal is null and check if it is equal to the `NullPrincipal.Default` instead.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem, I have created the `IPrincipalFactory` interface that can obtain the current principal without going through AutoFac:

```
public AuthorizationValidator : IAuthorizationValidator
{
  public AuthorizationValidator(IDataAccess dataAccess, IPrincipalFactory principalFactory)
  {
     // Save injected objects
     _dataAccess = dataAccess;
     _principal = principalFactory.GetCurrentPrincipal();
  }

  public bool CheckPermission(Guid objectId, Action action)
  {
     // Same as previous example
     ...
  }
}

public interface IPrincipalFactory
{
  IPrincipal GetCurrentPrincipal();
}
```

For the ASP.NET application I would register the following object as IPrincipalFactory:

```
public class IAspNetPrincipalFactory : IPrincipalFactory
{
  public IPrincipal GetCurrentPrincipal() => HttpContext.Current?.User;
}
```

Although this works, I am not completely happy with this solution.